# How can I pass a variable from one feature file to other

Tags: rest, karate

I have a variable in one of the scenario of a feature file which I need to use in the request body of second feature file.

```
For Example:

A.feature

Scenario: Test
Given url 'abc'
* def number = 12345
And request {tyu:'#(number)',dhd:'lkj'}
When method put
Then status 200

B.feature

Scenario: Test2
Given url 'pqr'
And request {tyu:'#(number)'}
When method put
Then status 200
```

Note: Number variable in A.feature is a 6 digit number which is randomly generated everytime and the same should be passed in B.feature file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you have two `Scenario`-s that depend on one another you have to combine them into one. Refer the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

But if you are really looking for how to initialize something and re-use it across *all* feature files, maybe you are looking for `karate.callSingle()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

```
var result = karate.callSingle('get-token.feature');
```

Comment: karate.callSingle() does the work, infact using this method reduces few line of code in every feature file of mine. Thanks a lot @Peter